# Solar Panel short section of string due to obstacle

Tags: photovoltaics, renewables, alternatives

Recently I have installed a set of 10 panels connected in series with 1 single Inverter. I have realised that for the first 2 hours 2 PVs have a cast shadow on them from a neighbourhood tank (that cannot shoot down :) )  and this will reduce the overall current of the system to the bare minimum.

I was thinking of using a timer to bypass the 2 PVs and take energy from the 8 remaining PVs for the first 2 hours. I was thinking of fitting 2 MC4 T-Connectors.

Should this incurr any implications due to short circuit currents in the last 2 PVs. Should I insert a low OHm load just in case?

[image]

Comment: To add a comment to this thread, I have tried the above setup but did not get any big improvement that worth the hassle. This is because the overall string voltage is reduced which will counter balance in the Current-Voltage, power output.

Answer (score 4):

You must open circuit the panels you're not using, do not short circuit them. Open circuit is fine, the panel just sits there and no current flows. You'll see quite a high voltage on the terminals (it'll be listed on the panel data sheet as "maximum open circuit voltage". If you short the panels you'll get up to "maximum short circuit current" which risks overheating the wiring inside the panel.

If you can I would test the idea by installing the plug/socket in the string and manually bypassing those two panels to make sure that you get enough extra power to make it worth doing properly.

Comment: Sure makes sense.